# Need help to display a Play Again button when user wins in a browser game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the "play again" button to be hidden and shown only when the user wins the game.
I'm having troubles with this task and i don't know how to approach it, i'm fairly new to javascript.

**Those are the instructions for the task**:

When user wins, display a Play Again button

You can show or hide an element by changing its style, see here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/showhide-element/

 You need to reset some variables and hide the Play Again button

 You need to flip all the cards

- To be able to flip the cards we need to be able to select all the cards and remove their
  flipped class
- This will require a loop similar to:

  // get all divs in the document
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
  divs[i].style.color = "green"; 
  }

**Those are the game files:**

HTML File:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/layout/logo.png">
    <h1>Memory Monsters</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/7.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/7.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/5.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/5.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>

  <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS file:

```
background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid darkcyan;
    color:darkcyan;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

.header img {
    float:right;
}

.card {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;    
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;

}

.card img {
    position: absolute;
}

.flipped .back {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript File:

```
// Those are global variables, they stay alive and reflect the state of the game
var elPreviousCard = null;
var flippedCouplesCount = 0;

// This is a constant that we dont change during the game (we mark those with CAPITAL letters)
var TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT = 3;

// Load an audio file
var audioWin = new Audio('sound/win.mp3');

// This function is called whenever the user click a card
function cardClicked(elCard) {

    // If the user clicked an already flipped card - do nothing and return from the function
    if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) {
        return;
    }

    // Flip it
    elCard.classList.add('flipped');

    // This is a first card, only keep it in the global variable
    if (elPreviousCard === null) {
        elPreviousCard = elCard;
    } else {
        // get the data-card attribute's value from both cards
        var card1 = elPreviousCard.getAttribute('data-card');
        var card2 = elCard.getAttribute('data-card');

        // No match, schedule to flip them back in 1 second
        if (card1 !== card2){
            setTimeout(function () {
                elCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard = null;
            }, 1000)

        } else {
            // Yes! a match!
            flippedCouplesCount++;
            elPreviousCard = null;

            // All cards flipped!
            if (TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT === flippedCouplesCount) {
                audioWin.play();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Well, not be obnoxious, but the instructions are very clear. Please try to work them out first before asking for a solution. Make an effort and when you run into a problem, update your question specify the problem you run into.

Comment: I've tried to follow the instructions but without succsess so far. like i said, i'm new to this and i have no idea how to create button to be shown only when the players wins, i don't know what code to write and where to place it exactly. i'm asking this question after hours on hours that i tried to do this for myself but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean variable and place it within the 'win' if() block. Once you win, set that variable to true and add that to your HTML when it's true. Make sure you reset the variable to false if you restart the game.

If you don't know how to add HTML elements with javascript, here's a simple example. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to insert your button (or toggle a class to show/hide it) and then remove all `flipped` class via a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) & [looping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) on this class.

example *(probably not the shortest way to do it)*

```js
// Those are global variables, they stay alive and reflect the state of the game
var elPreviousCard = null;
var flippedCouplesCount = 0;

// This is a constant that we dont change during the game (we mark those with CAPITAL letters)
var TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT = 3;

// Load an audio file
var audioWin = new Audio('sound/win.mp3');

// This function is called whenever the user click a card
function cardClicked(elCard) {
  // If the user clicked an already flipped card - do nothing and return from the function
  if (elCard.classList.contains("flipped")) {
    return;
  }

  // Flip it
  elCard.classList.add("flipped");

  // This is a first card, only keep it in the global variable
  if (elPreviousCard === null) {
    elPreviousCard = elCard;
  } else {
    // get the data-card attribute's value from both cards
    var card1 = elPreviousCard.getAttribute("data-card");
    var card2 = elCard.getAttribute("data-card");

    // No match, schedule to flip them back in 1 second
    if (card1 !== card2) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        elCard.classList.remove("flipped");
        elPreviousCard.classList.remove("flipped");
        elPreviousCard = null;
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      //alert('Yes! a match!');
      flippedCouplesCount++;
      elPreviousCard = null;

      // All cards flipped!
      if (TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT === flippedCouplesCount) {
        audioWin.play();
        
        // and finally add a button to call resetCard() 
        document.getElementById("replay").innerHTML =
          '<button onclick="resetCard();">replay</button>';
      }
    }
  }
}

function resetCard() {// to erase the flipped classes
  var cardclass = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (i = 0; i < cardclass.length; i++) {
    cardclass[i].classList.remove("flipped");
    document.getElementById("replay").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid darkcyan;
    color:darkcyan;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

.header img {
    float:right;
}

.card {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;    
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;

}

.card img {
    position: absolute;
}

.flipped .back {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=logo.png">
    <h1>Memory Monsters</h1>
    <p id="replay"><!-- button will show up here --></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=1.png">
    <img class="back" src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=7.png">
    <img class="back" src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=1.png">
    <img class="back" src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=7.png">
    <img class="back" src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=5.png">
    <img class="back" src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=5.png">
    <img class="back" src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=back.png">
  </div>
```